# Change GridView cells strings on Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that has a column called `Active` which shows either a `1` (for active) or a `-1` for inactive.

However as this is being implemented into a front end UI I do not want users to be presented with what seems to them as useless integers, however a `Active` or `Not active` to be presented in the GridView on `Page_Load`.

The code would look something like -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code here to modify the column 'Active' in the GridView
        //GridView ID="GV1"

        if (row.Cells[1].Text == "1")
        {
            row.Cells[1].Text = "Active";
        }
        if (row.Cells[1].Text == "-1")
        {
            row.Cells[1].Text = "Not Active";
        }

    }
```

And the column in the GridView is -

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Active" DataField="Active" SortExpression="Active"></asp:BoundField>
```

How can I do this as I do not want to edit the database in order for the UI to be more presentable?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [OnRowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) Gridview event.